# Replace string or html onload in AJAX using JS and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having a problem changing the string content of a particular DIV tag when using AJAX.

For some reason I can change string content when using an onclick function. This works;

```
<div id="demo">Will change on click? </div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Yes, Successfully changes" ;
    }
</script>
```

However this does not;

```
<div id="demo2">Will this change?</div>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Yes, Successfully changes" ;
    }
</script>
```

Both approaches work on the page itself,  but import that page using AJAX, and only the onclick method works. This issue persists when trying both JavaScript and JQuery.  What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by importing that page using AJAX?

Comment: Maybe that was the wrong term.  But basically, using AJAX to filter results from the db.  The external file AJAX is using within the page contains these commands.

Comment: Do you mean that the above snippet is added to DOM via AJAX call?

Comment: Yes sir, that's exactly what I mean.  
Please excuse my lack of clarity. This is all so new to me.

Comment: It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/mqr0nsvj/

Comment: Yes, it works on a stand alone page.  But when using AJAX to call that page, the onload method fails.

Comment: `onload` occurred in the main page long before any ajax content is inserted. It isn't going to be triggered again. Same with `document.ready` ... any new code wrapped in that will fire immediately

Comment: In that case, you don't need `onload` or the function. Just run the code inside directly.

Comment: On load jQuery String Replace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415003/replace-contents-of-div-on-page-load-with-jquery#48090587

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try registering an event handler using jQuery's `.ajaxcomplete` http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/ . This event gets fired when an AJAX request finishes which is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

User the following way to update the content using Ajax

```
<div id="demo">Let AJAX change this text</div>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Try it</button>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Go to following link for more ajax examples.
[Ajax Examples](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp)

Comment: But this still requires a button, which is what I'm trying to eliminate.

Comment: What exactly is your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax_info.txt"
}).done(function( data ) {
    $("#demo").html(data);
  });

});
</script>
```

on ready function you can call ajax and change the content

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery ready function and call your function inside ready function. 
like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  myFunction();
});
```

Comment: Such as this?
    $("document").ready(function() {
        $("#demo").text("Yes, changed");
        $("#demo").html("Yes, changed");
    });

--  Bcuz again it works on the page alone,  but used with AJAX and it does not.  What is sooooo strange, is that I have it working just fine on another site,  but I can't seem to isolate what the difference is.

Comment: You can use on click instead of ready function with ajax.  something like this : $(document).on('click',function(){myFunction(); });
OR
call function after ajax success

Answer (score 0):

/* jQuery Onload String Replace OR jQuery Onload String Change */

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var strNewString = $('body').html().replace(/\On hold/g,'Processing');
    $('body').html(strNewString);
});

</script>
```